# Django order_by('-id') is extremely slow when combined with more than one filter

Tags: mysql, django

I have a model **Line** with a **group** Foreign key.
I want to get the **last 30 Lines under a certain id**, within a single group. To do that, I use this query:

`Line.objects.filter(group_id=8460, id__lt=10333449).order_by("-id")[:30]`

My problem is that this query takes 1.5s to get executed, whereas these three are done almost instantly (<50ms):

- **Without group_id**: `Line.objects.filter(id__lt=10333449).order_by("-id")[:30]`
- **Without ordering**:
  `Line.objects.filter(group_id=8460, id__lt=10333449)[:30]`
- **Without id__lt**: `Line.objects.filter(group_id=8460).order_by("-id")[:30]`

For info, I have 10M+ lines in total and about 13k lines in this group alone.

How can I make the query faster when using both `id__lt` and `order_by('-id')`?

The model looks like this:

```
class Line(TransactionSubject):
    objects = ModelManager()

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lines")

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Character, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="lines")
    tone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="neutral")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    action = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_storytelling = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_chat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_description = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)

    character_state = models.ForeignKey(CharacterState, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                        related_name="lines")

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    whispered_to = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name="whispered_lines", blank=True)

    yet_to_read = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="unread_lines", blank=True)

    party = models.ForeignKey(Party, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="lines")

    language = models.ForeignKey(FictionalLanguage, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                                 related_name="lines")

    beginner_speakers = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name="lines_beginner", blank=True)
    intermediate_speakers = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name="lines_intermediate", blank=True)
    fluent_speakers = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name="lines_fluent", blank=True)

    transactions = GenericRelation(CoinTransaction, related_name="transactions")

    tagged_characters = models.ManyToManyField(Character, related_name="lines_tagging", blank=True)
    tagged_users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="lines_tagging", blank=True)
```

An `explain()` on the query gives:

```
1 SIMPLE playerdata_line None index_merge PRIMARY,playerdata_line_group_id_429944d8,playerdata__group_id_d5c0b7_idx,playerdata__group_id_667c13_idx,group_id_index playerdata_line_group_id_429944d8,PRIMARY 8,4 None 11677 100.0 Using intersect(playerdata_line_group_id_429944d8,PRIMARY); Using where; Using filesort
```

The resulting query is:

```
(1.339) SELECT `playerdata_line`.`id`, `playerdata_line`.`wood`, `playerdata_line`.`copper`, `playerdata_line`.`silver`, `playerdata_line`.`gold`, `playerdata_line`.`platinum`, `playerdata_line`.`legendary`, `playerdata_line`.`total_value`, `playerdata_line`.`group_id`, `playerdata_line`.`user_id`, `playerdata_line`.`author_id`, `playerdata_line`.`tone`, `playerdata_line`.`content`, `playerdata_line`.`action`, `playerdata_line`.`is_storytelling`, `playerdata_line`.`is_chat`, `playerdata_line`.`is_description`, `playerdata_line`.`is_comment`, `playerdata_line`.`character_state_id`, `playerdata_line`.`created`, `playerdata_line`.`edited`, `playerdata_line`.`party_id`, `playerdata_line`.`language_id` FROM `playerdata_line` WHERE (`playerdata_line`.`group_id` = 8460 AND `playerdata_line`.`id` < 10333449) ORDER BY `playerdata_line`.`id` DESC  LIMIT 30; args=(8460, 10333449)
```

Comment: Can you share your model? An index could be the solution

Comment: @IainShelvington I assume an index could work but I am not sure how to implement it. What do you need to see from the model? I didn't share it to not overcomplicate the question, as there are about 22 other fields on the it.

Comment: An index over `group_id` and `id` would probably speed up this query since they are the fields queried against and then sorted by. The model and just these two field definitions could maybe help with suggestions for how to define the index

Comment: @IainShelvington I shared the model, but I really think it is just making it all more confusing ^^'. Group is a foreign key, so django indexes it by default, isn't it? Same goes for 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using [Iain Shelvington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552859/3904557) as a base.

Creating the index was the first step, but the problem is that Django was not using that index first.

I fixed it by using the [`django-mysql`](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension to force the usage of the index with `use_index`

```
Line.objects.filter(group_id=8460, id__lt=10333449).use_index('group_id_index').order_by("-id")[:30]
```

The query went from 1.4s to 40ms :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding an index over fields that are commonly queried together is a good way to speed up those queries. In your case an index over `group` and `id` seems appropriate

```
class Line(TransactionSubject):

    # fields...

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['group', 'id'], name='group_id_index'),
        ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the query still takes about 1.4s with this index added.

Comment: You definitely ran makemigrations and migrate? The next step to debug would be to see output from an `EXPLAIN` on the query

Comment: Yes, did makemigrations and migrate. Even gave it time to index everything. I added the print of `explain` to my post.

Comment: Can you give the index a name (added to the answer) and show the output of `explain` again? It's difficult to know which index in the output matches the one added

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there is another field being filtered by. Can you add the full SQL query too?

Comment: Added the SQL query. The number in parenthesis is the time it takes to execute in seconds.